# Objective c : Get ISO Formated Date from String '2015-11-25T00:00:00.000Z'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, isodate

In our app we are getting Date string ***`"2015-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"`*** from server.
Now we have to convert this string into into NSDate.

I've used the following code for conversion. Which is having an **ISO Date Format**.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];

    NSDate *outputDate =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"];
```

But it returns ***`null`***.

Can anyone please suggest where did I make the mistake...

Comment: Do NOT quote the Z in the date format. This results in the date being parsed in local time instead of the timezone specified in the date string (UTC in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.
It returns:

```
(lldb) po outputDate
2015-11-25 00:00:00 +0000
```

Try next code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

NSDate *outputDate =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"];
```

Comment: Do NOT quote the `Z` in the date format. This results in the date being parsed in local time instead of the timezone specified in the date string (UTC in this case).

Comment: @rmaddy are you sure? According to the question there is literal `Z`, not time zone.

Comment: The `Z` in the date string is the timezone. It means "Zulu" which is a synonym for UTC timezone.

Comment: @rmaddy according to Apple docs single Z character should be literal in `dateFormat` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: OK, I see what's going on. For some stupid reason, the author of that Apple code needlessly quotes the `Z` and forces the date formatter's timezone to UTC. There's no need for that. Instead of ignoring the date string's timezone and forcing a specific timezone on the date formatter, the more correct solution is to allow the formatter to extract the timezone from the date string. This means you shouldn't quote the Z and you shouldn't set a specific timezone on the formatter.

Comment: @rmaddy now I'm completely agree with you. I'll simplify my answer.